# How to bundle extra files with jlink image

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, jlink

I'm using Gradle with the [Badass JLink Plugin](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) to distribute my software. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to include certain files in the image (e.g. README.md, some test input, etc.). I assume it requires some work in `build.gradle`, but I've so far not been able to figure it out.

It's easy to do this using the `application` plugin's `distZip` functionality by following [these instructions](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:the_distribution), but I prefer to distribute using a jlink image so users don't need to have Java installed.

Is this even possible to do with jlink? If not, it seems like a huge drawback.

Comment: `jlink` merely assembles modules;  the adding of files is done at the creation of each module which will be linked.  Things like test input probably should be in the module’s .jar file, where they can be accessed as [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).  Other files can be included in a .jmod file using the file category options of `jmod`, like `--man-pages`, `--config`, and `--legal-notices`.  I don’t know how this is done using the Gradle plugin you have referenced.

Comment: @VGR: thanks for the response. When I say "test input", I don't mean unit tests, but sample files that can be processed by my users (using my software) when they follow a tutorial outlined in the README. Therefore, it seems to me like the .jar is the wrong place to host them, as they won't be able to navigate inside of it using the file chooser in my software. jmod is new to me, but it seems like something that's not conducive to opening in a simple text editor like a README file, which is what I would like to keep things as easy as possible for my users.

Comment: It’s worth noting that you can do whatever you want to a jlink’d image tree.  You are free to add your own directories, including sample data directories.  You can put the README in the root of the image tree, or in a new directory of your choosing such as `docs`.  Getting the program to look in that directory might require modifying the executable script generated by jlink’s `--launcher` option, so it passes the directory as a system property or command line argument.

Comment: @VGR: that sounds like exactly what I want to do! I don't actually need the program to look in any directories, I can rely on the user to navigate there. If you post an example of how to automate this with Groovy in `build.gradle` as the answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I’d like to, but I know very little Groovy or Gradle.  Hopefully someone else will step up.  If not, I may research it and make an attempt when time permits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the useful comments from @VGR, I was able to come up with this solution to my problem in `build.gradle`:

```
def JLINK_DIR = "$buildDir/myApp"

tasks.jlink.doLast {
    copy {
        from("/") {
            include "README.md", "LICENSE"
        }
        into JLINK_DIR + "/docs"
    }
    copy {
        includeEmptyDirs = false
        from("/path/to/sample/input") {
            include "sample_input_1/*"
            include "sample_input_2/*"
            exclude "output"
        }
        into JLINK_DIR + "/sample_input"
    }
}
```

The [Gradle Docs on copy](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) and the [Badass JLink Plugin examples](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/#examples) were especially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this, it really helped. For me, I was trying to add to installer. I had to do the following:

```
def JLINK_DIR = "$buildDir/jpackage/MyApp"

tasks.jpackage.doFirst {
    copy {
        from("/config") {
            include "config.properties"
        }
        into JLINK_DIR + "/config"
    }
}
```